# my array not convert into string for excell report

Tags: php

I have one question for array to string convert notice in php 
when i send my array to function at that time i fetch notice like array to string conversion
i have user store data into array like this

```
if(count($data) == 5 || count($data) == 6){
    array_push($eventsArray, array("customer" => $client_name));
  } 
  else if (count($data) == 3 || count($data) == 4) {
    array_push($eventsArray, array("customer" => $client_name));
  }
```

and i use this function to pass array in this function

```
fputcsv($fp, $eventsArray);
```

but after output in excell report i have see only error like

[image: this is my excell report image i fetch this error every time]]

Comment: You should post sample data for `$eventsArray`. Please try to create a MCVE (minimal verfifyable and complete example): http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: can you give me one example

Comment: use foreach loop. `fputcsv` require single dimension array

Comment: fputcs() does not work with multi-dimensional arrays..... just do `array_push($eventsArray, $client_name);`